# Node.js - Unable to use callback in if statement

Tags: node.js, callback, socket.io

Hi I am trying to execute a callback in a if statement but I get "TypeError: callback is not a function"
This is my code:

```
socket.on('authenticate', function (data, callback) {

    // this works
    callback("false");

    // this doesn't work
    if (data == "abc") {
        callback("true");
    }

});
```

Comment: 'authenticate' is not an event of _socket.io_. What do you use that raises 'authenticate' event? That is where you need to find out what is the expected API? It seems it is not supporting the callback parameter, or it is not being pass on properly when _emit()_ was called.

Comment: @num8er Look at https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-on-eventname-callback. The function that OP passed in is the socket.io's callback, in his example the socket.io callback is expecting 2 parameters where the 2nd parameter is another callback function.

Comment: @num8er no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check if callable function is passed, at least just do `if(callback)`

in Your problem there may be situation that clientside not waiting for callback (done emit call without passing callback argument).

Try this solution:

```
socket.on('authenticate', function (data, callback) {
    console.debug('socket authenticate:', data); // for debug purposes

    if (data == "abc") {
        if(callback) { // callback may not be passed
          callback(null, true); // keep in mind in callbacks first argument is error second is result
        }
        return; // return will prevent execution to go down, because most of times used for resulting call.
    }

    if(callback) { // callback may not be passed
      callback("Not authenticated", false); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works now, it was the "if(callback)" part that was required

Comment: Forget about the `return` and `if` guard. I'm still struggling to understand on why the `callback` function would get unset after it got invoked the first time?

Comment: @SamuelToh I think problem problem even happens on first callback. Also I think it's not been unset, simply it's not been passed. Victor has not shared all of code to have more info why...

Comment: @num8er I agree on this. For replication purpose I think OP should consider revealing the `server` code and the `stacktrace` as well.I don't believe the fact that the first call worked and the second didn't. I suspect the error is talking about the first call failing. If so then the `callback` not getting passed through make a lot of sense. I think OP may have a greater problem here. A `if` guard statement could be just masking the issue.